# Angular Add Pager on url for offset and limit

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I need to add pager on my page. Data is too large so i want to show like this On first pager its show 50 data (On url pass offset 0 and limit 50) Then on next It will pass offset 50 to limit 100.

```js
getClaims() {
    if(this.userFilter.company_id){
        this.url = 'http://url.com/get_company_employee.php? 
        offset=0&limit=50&company_id='+this.userFilter.company_id;
    }
    else{
        this.url = 'http://ur.com/get_company_employee.php?offset=0&limit=10';
    }

    this.clientData = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url,{responseType: 'json'}).
        subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.data = data.records;
        });
};
```

Comment: Still dont understand your question so you want to update the offset everytime you go to another page ?

Comment: I need to add pager in my page . like 1 2 3 4 5 6 so on , If i click on 1 so in url the offset value is 0 and limit is 50, then if i select 2 then the url offset value is 50 and limit is 100.

Comment: Then I think that is just a logic from your paginator in template